# does subprocess module runs all commands in windows 11? and is there any diff between using same code in linux and windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, subprocess

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["date"])
```

**output:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

It worked in linux but did not work in windows 11

Is there any diff between using same code in linux and windows while using subprocess module

Comment: you can run the same command in cmd directly and check what output you are getting, then you will know the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

this code will also work on windows

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["date"], shell=True)
```